BottomSheetDialogFragment - Landscape doesnt take full width
in android with xml I have my own class which inherits from BottomSheetDialogFragment, I did customize it to occupy the full width and height as follows:
But for some reason in landscape it doesn't take the whole screen width rather it getting cut for all devices like 10% from both of the sides(but the height actually does take the whole height possible).
globalLayoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                
                BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) getDialog();
                if (dialog != null) {
                    View bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
                    if (bottomSheet != null) {
                       
                        BottomSheetBehavior<View> behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
                        behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                        bottomSheet.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {
                            int screenWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                            int screenHeight = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

                            
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = bottomSheet.getLayoutParams();
                            layoutParams.width = screenWidth;
                            layoutParams.height = screenHeight; full height
                            bottomSheet.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        });

